# Query with distinct keyword and subquery not working in Hive with udf

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

Not working query:

```
select  lookup(city, state, tax,'addresslookup')
from (select distinct  city, state, tax 
from open_glory.addylookup) a
```

Working query (without distinct):

```
select  lookup(city, state, tax,'addresslookup')
from (select city, state, tax 
from open_glory.addylookup) a
```

UDF code:

```
public class Lookup extends GenericUDF {

 private static String delimiter = "|";
 private ConcurrentHashMap < String, HashMap < String, String >> fileMap = new ConcurrentHashMap < String, HashMap < String, String >> ();

 protected String loggedInUser;
 protected String loggedInApplication;

 private transient GenericUDFUtils.StringHelper returnHelper;

 private transient StringConverter[] stringConverter;

 private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Lookup.class.getName());

 @Override
 public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arguments)
 throws UDFArgumentException {
     if (arguments.length < 2) {
         throw new UDFArgumentLengthException(
             "lookup takes 2 or more arguments");
     }

     stringConverter = new StringConverter[arguments.length];

     for (int i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
         if (arguments[0].getCategory() != Category.PRIMITIVE) {
             throw new UDFArgumentException(
                 "lookup only takes primitive types");
         }
         stringConverter[i] = new PrimitiveObjectInspectorConverter.StringConverter(
             (PrimitiveObjectInspector) arguments[i]);
     }

     setLoggedInUser();

     returnHelper = new GenericUDFUtils.StringHelper(
         PrimitiveCategory.STRING);
     LOG.info("initialize successful");
     return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableStringObjectInspector;
 }

 private void setLoggedInUser() {
     if (loggedInUser == null) {
         loggedInUser = SessionState.get().getUserName();
         if (loggedInUser != null) {
             int idx = loggedInUser.indexOf('.');
             loggedInApplication = idx > -1 ? loggedInUser.substring(0, idx) : null;
         }
     }
 }

 private void initMap(String f) {
     LOG.info("initMap involked");
     if (loggedInApplication == null)
         throw new NullPointerException(
             "Unable to retrieve application name from user.");
     String filePath = "/basepath/" + loggedInApplication.toLowerCase() + "/" + f +
         ".txt";
     String line = null;
     try {
         LOG.info("filePath =" + filePath);
         FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
         FSDataInputStream in = fs.open(new Path(filePath));
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in ));
         HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
             // ignore comment lines
             if (line.startsWith("#")) {
                 continue;
             }
             String[] strs = line.split("\t");
             if (strs.length == 2) {
                 map.put(strs[0].toUpperCase().trim(), strs[1].trim());
             } else if (strs.length > 2) {
                 map.put(getKey(strs), strs[strs.length - 1].trim());
             }
         }
         fileMap.put(f, map);
         br.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
     }
 }

 public Text getValue(String s, String f) {
     initMap(f);
     HashMap < String, String > map = fileMap.get(f);

     LOG.info("getValue() fileMap =" + fileMap);
     String v = map.get(s);
     return v == null ? null : new Text(v);
 }

 @Override
 public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {


     String val = buildVal(arguments);

     String lookupFile = (String) stringConverter[arguments.length - 1].convert(arguments[arguments.length - 1].get());

     Text returnVal = getValue(val.toUpperCase(), lookupFile.toLowerCase());

     return returnVal == null ? null : returnHelper.setReturnValue(returnVal.toString());
 }

 @Override
 public String getDisplayString(String[] arg0) {
     return "lookup()";
 }

 private String buildVal(DeferredObject[] arguments) throws HiveException {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     int cnt = arguments.length - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
         builder.append((String) stringConverter[i].convert(arguments[i].get()));
         if (i < cnt - 1) {
             builder.append(delimiter);
         }
     }
     return builder.toString();
 }

 private String getKey(String[] strs) {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     int cnt = strs.length - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
         builder.append(strs[i].toUpperCase().trim());
         if (i < cnt - 1) {
             builder.append(delimiter);
         }
     }
     return builder.toString();
 }
}
```